# Android getting errors but no red error marks anywhere

Tags: android

Android getting errors but no red error marks anywhere.   The Problems tab stated: Android Packaging Problem. I dont know what to do.... please help.......

I am building a program out of a book entitled  “Learn Android In 24 Hours”. It is a simple game called “Been There, Done That!”.  It has 7 different activities :

1.QuizHelpActivity:

```
package com.android.triviaquiz;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help);
```

2.QuizSplashActivity:

```
package com.android.triviaquiz;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

3.QuizGameActivity:

```
package com.android.triviaquiz;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
```

4.QuizScoreActivity:

```
package com.android.triviaquiz;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.score);
```

5.QuizSettingsActivity:

```
package com.android.triviaquiz;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
```

6.QuizMenuActivity:

```
package com.android.triviaquiz;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
```

7.and they all extend QuizActivity:

```
package com.android.triviaquiz;
   import android.app.Activity;

    public class QuizActivity extends Activity{ 
public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES="GamePrefs";
```

What could I be doing wrong?????????

manifest file:

```
<activity android:label="menu" android:name=".QuizMenuActivity"></activity>
<activity android:label="scores" android:name=".QuizScoresActivity"></activity>
<activity android:label="settings" android:name=".QuizSettingsActivity"></activity>
<activity android:label="game" android:name=".QuizGameActivity"></activity>
<activity android:label="help" android:name=".QuizHelpActivity"></activity>
<activity android:label="parent" android:name=".QuizActivity"></activity>
</application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you want me to post my manifest file or my androidmanifest.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you mentioned all these activities inside your manifest file with the correct package name? Please check the same and see..

Comment: In the Android Manifest.xml>>application tab section i registered all activties on the application node part of the page. I think that what i was supposed to do. Is it????

Comment: Please put a "." in front of your class files. For eg: <activity android:label="menu" android:name=".QuizMenuActivity"></activity>

Comment: I have put a period (".") in front  of all my activities and updated my post as well.  I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and build the android project.

Comment: try to change SDK level to other say 3.0